# Attach Existing managed data disk to existing azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

We need to create a Managed data disk and attach it to Existing VM.
We are using ARM template to create managed disk, but i am not sure in same ARM how we can attach it to VM?

i am using Add-AzureRmVMDataDisk to attach managed data disk to vm but it is expecting VHDURI parameter, not sure how we will get that for managed datadisk.

**Note:** we have limitation that we can't use New-AzureRmDisk to create data disk as our compute module is not latest version, so it is not supporting this cmdlet and upgrading this module causing so many issues to other cmdlets that we already used in other functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

To add an existing managed disk to a virtual machine in ARM you can use the property dataDisks under the storageProfile object of the virtual machine resource.

The dataDisks property accepts an array of objects, one object per data disk that you want to attach to the VM. The example array below would add 3 data disks to the virtual machine.

```
[
    {
      "lun": 0,
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '-datadisk1')]",
      "createOption": "attach",
      "managedDisk": {
        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/', concat(parameters('virtualdisk1name')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "lun": 1,
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '-datadisk2')]",
      "createOption": "attach",
      "managedDisk": {
        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/', '-datadisk2'))]"
      }
    },
    {
      "lun": 2,
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '-datadisk3')]",
      "createOption": "attach",
      "managedDisk": {
        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/' ,'-datadisk3'))]"
      }
    }
]
```

You can see a full example of the virtual machine template [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines), which shows the dataDisks property of the storageProfile object.

Comment: When I am trying to use above ARM, I got below error                                                        "Could not find member 'managedDisk' on object of type 'DataDisk'. Path 'properties.storageProfile.dataDisks[0].managedDisk', line 1, position 139."

Comment: When i tried by removing "managedDisk": {..} section I am getting error as "Addition of a managed disk to a VM with blob based disks is not supported."

Comment: Could you post up your ARM Template please? Based on the error message it sounds like you didn't pass the objects in as an array in your ARM template. You need to pass an Array of objects to dataDisk

Comment: The error sounds like you have unmanaged disks on the VM already, if so, you can't add a managed disk to it...

Comment: I would agree with @bmoore-msft - having re-read the error message that should have been obvious. If you post up your template we can confirm, as you weren't able to add the data disks it might be that you are using an unmanaged OS disk.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you take a note of three things when you are trying to attach a managed data disk in Azure templates:

1. **API version** - i had an older API version while creating the VM resource, I changed it to "2018-06-01", since the old version did not support addition of managed disks in a VM resource in an ARM template.
2. **Unmanaged OS Disk** - I had OS Disk which was an unmanaged disk, i removed all the attributes while just keeping the createOption attribute, "createOption": "FromImage", to ensure it creates a managed disk and not uses the storageaccount for unmanaged disk.
3. **DataDisk Name** - I had put in a name from the DataDisk, i removed that attribute from the template.

VHD URI is the URI which you use to create a new data disk.
You can use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-managed-disk-from-vhd) to create a managed disk using PowerShell.

You can also create a managed disk in the same Azure template as the VM and attach the disk as a data disk to the VM Template which looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/disks",
  "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
  "name": "YourDataDiskName",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "creationData": {
      "createOption": "Import",
      "sourceUri": "https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/yourcontainer/VHDName.vhd"
    }
  }
},
{
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "MyWindowsVM",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "VirtualMachine"
      },
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "Standard_A2"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "MyWindowsVM",
          "adminUsername": "someusername",
          "adminPassword": "somepassword"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            "offer": "WindowsServer",
            "sku": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {            
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          },
          "dataDisks": [
            {
              "lun": 0,
              "createOption": "Attach",
              "managedDisk": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', 'YourDataDiskName')]"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', 'myVMNic')]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'diagstorageaccountname'), '2016-01-01').primaryEndpoints.blob]"
          }
        }
      },
      "resources": [
      ]
    }
```

From the template you can see that I create a resource Data Disk using the VHD specified and attached it to the VM in storageprofile.datadisk section.

I hope that this helps!

Comment: I have edited the post to answer the original question, I genuinely hope that this helps, if not then go ahead and delete the post.